# Constructing Class Variables

Tags: php, class, constructor

I am trying to make my class variables in the 'global scope' of my web application so they can be used within other classes easily and throughout the web application when you call them. Here is my Articles Class for my web application.

```
class Articles {

   //  Defined variables that constructs an Article
   private $id
   private $title
   private $summary
   private $content
   private $author

   public function __construct($id, $title, $summary, $content, $author) {
      //  Constructs our Article by default
      $this->id      = $id;
      $this->title   = $title;
      $this->summary = $summary;
      $this->content = $content;
      $this->author  = $author;
   }
}
```

And here is my init.php file

```
//  Require the Articles and ArticlesHandler Class
require 'Articles/Articles.php';
require 'Articles/ArticlesHander.php';
```

If I needed to call the $title in the ArticlesHandler, does it have access to just using $title or do I need it call it using $this->title? Or is there a better method to do this?

Comment: Nothing here actually creates any class instances.... don't confuse a class definition with a class variable (there's no such thing unless you mean a class instance) and learn about autoloaders rather than handling includes for everthing in your init.php file

Comment: I do the instance of the class when it is called in the file. The init is a catch all for the Db, Articles, Members, etc. The instance is called within the index.php. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Traven Could you edit your question to show which file creates the instance (e.g. `$article = new Article(1, 'Hello', 'World', '!', 'me');`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily return the values, save them in a variable and declare it global, for example

```
public function show() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

Then after you initiate your class, you can do this

```
$id = $class->show();
global $id;
```

Another approach would be if you changed the variable scope in your class to public

then you can easily do the following

```
$id = $class->id;
global $id;
```

Comment: "I am trying to make my class variables in the 'global scope'" @user2411276, I only answered the OP's question

Comment: You really should have advised the OP that it wasn't a good idea to maintain everything in global scope, and introduced them to dependency injection and/or factory patterns rather than showing how to use global (especially as you haven't done a particularly good job of it either)

Answer (score -2):

```
    You need to create an object of the class to access the variables. In your case it will be 

        $articles = new Articles(1,'mytitle','test','mycontent','myauthor');
        echo $articles->title; // mytitle

    If you can give more information on what your ArticlesHandler class is doing, I could edit my answer to your requirements.

**Edit:**

    private variables are meant to be private to the class , so they cannot be accessed outside the class.

    There are different ways to address this:
    1.  create a public function and return the private variable through it. 
    public function displayTitle(){
    return $this->title;
    }

    2. You could make ArticlesHanlder subclass of Articles and make the variables in Articles protected, so it is accessible by the classes that inherit Articles class.
    then you could just use it like $this->title in the ArticlesHanlder.
```

Comment: I did not read the problem properly at first, since the problem is to make the variable in the Articles class available globally, you should declare them as public.